# CodeHS Python, remove all from string

Tags: python

I am using CodeHS for my Computer Science Principles class and one of the problems in the Strings section is really confusing me. We have to remove all of one string from another string.

These are the official instructions:

> Write a function called remove_all_from_string that takes two strings, and returns a copy of the first string with all instances of the second string removed. You can assume that the second string is only one letter, like "a".

We **are required** use:

1. A function definition with parameters
2. A while loop
3. The find method
4. Slicing and the + operator
5. A return statement

We are expected to only have to use those 5 things to make it work. 
I attempted to write this program but my function doesn't do anything and I am really stumped.

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    while letter in word:
        x=word.find(letter)
        if x==-1:
            continue
        else:
            return x

    print word[:x] + word[x+1:]

remove_all_from_string("alabama", "a")
```

Comment: Return will exit before the print statement

Comment: so it looks like you are returning as soon as you find a match? The reason why nothing happens is on the first match you will return x and that function will quit

Answer (score 2):

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    while letter in word:
        x=word.find(letter)
        if x == -1:
            continue
        else:
            word = word[:x] + word[x+1:]
    return word

print(remove_all_from_string("hello", "l"))
```

Comment: Please comment your answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would obviously just be

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    return word.replace(letter, "")
```

However, considering the parameters, another way we could do this is like so:

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    while letter in word:
        x=word.find(letter)
        if x == -1:
            continue
        else:
            word = word[:x] + word[x+1:]
    return word
```

You could run this and print it by typing

```
>>> print(remove_all_from_string("Word Here", "e"))
#returns Word hr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    letters = len(word)
    while letters >= 0:
        x=word.find(letter)
        if x == -1:
            letters = letters - 1
            continue
        else:
            # Found a match
            word = word[:x] + word[x+1:]
            letters = letters - 1

    return word

remove_all_from_string("alabama", "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):

    while letter in word:
    
        num = word.find(letter)
    
        word = word[:num] + word[num+1:]

    return word
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

I have this so far and it keeps saying that message is not defined and when I define it with find_secret_word it says "find_secret_word" is not defined, what do I do?
This is my code:

```
word = "bananas"
letter = "na"
index = word.find(letter)
def remove_all_from_string(word, letter):
    while letter in word:
        x=word.find(letter)
        if x == -1:
            continue
        else:
            word = word[:x] + word[x+1:]
    return word
    word = word[:index] + word[index+len(letter):]
print(remove_all_from_string("hello", "l"))
def find_secret_word(message):
    while True:
        return hidden_word
    hidden_word = "iCjnyAyT"
for letter in message:
    if letter.upper():
        hidden_word = hidden_word + letter
print (find_secret_word(message))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).